# Old Self-Answered question shows up in unanswered list

Tags: support, status-completed

This question [about Android's MediaPlayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2511045/streaming-to-the-android-mediaplayer) Was answered in the question rather than in the answer. I'm not familiar when self answered questions became available but this question appears to be needing an edit as its protected by community and for me to copy the answer would just be stealing reputation from the asker. This question is answer at the top of [Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android?sort=unanswered) tagged unanswered.  Could a mod create a correctly attributed answer by moving part of the question to an answer?

Answer (score 2):

Done, but you didn't need a mod.  Next time, you can just do it yourself.

Despite the fact that we wear capes, mods don't have the ability to post answers on behalf of other users anyway, so just quote the entire passage in a new answer and CW it.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know I could do it myself, thank you!